# Spring mvc data blinding while mapping checkbox

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to make an product object in a view. Everything is working except the isInfinite checkbox. it always false.
Im new to mvc things i know that the names shuild be equal and i dont know whats wrong.

I added my product class that im trying to map and form. In for everything is the same, even checkbox, but its doesnt work

If enyone can help please

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;
    @Column(name = "productStatus")
    private ProductStatus productStatus;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;
    @Column(name = "isInfinite")
    private boolean isInfinite;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    private Long previewImageId;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;
    private LocalDateTime dateOfCreated;

    @PrePersist
    private void onCreate() { dateOfCreated = LocalDateTime.now(); }
```

my ftlh file

```
<form action="/product/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="productName">Название товара</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control"
                       id="productName" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Цена товара</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" required class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">₽</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="amount">Колличество товара</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" required class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">шт.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="isInfinite">Неограниченное колличество товара</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <form type="checkbox" name="isInfinite" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Описание товара</label>
                <textarea required class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input required type="file" name="file1" id="file1">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file1">Первая фотография к товару</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file2">Вторая фотография к товару</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file3">Третья фотография к товару</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <button type="submit" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-dark">Добавить</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `input` tag instead of `from`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="isInfinite">Неограниченное количество товара</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isInfinite" name="isInfinite" checked required>
  </div>
</div>
```